# Как расшарить изображение, которую достаю с сервера?

Tags: ios, swift

Достаю изображение с инета, стоит задача расшарить изображение, например в WhatsApp.

Смотрел англоязычные ответы, к сожалению не подошло.

Вот что я на данный момент пробую, но не выходит.

NOTE: `newsAboutOne[indexImage].image)` - это ссылка на изображение.

```
// нажатие на кнопку шаринга.
func actionBasket(){

    let image = UIImageView()
    image.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: newsAboutOne[indexImage].image))

    share(shareText: "forest", shareImage: image.image)
}

func share(shareText:String?,shareImage:UIImage?){

    var objectsToShare = [AnyObject]()

    if let shareTextObj = shareText{
        objectsToShare.append(shareTextObj as AnyObject)
    }

    if let shareImageObj = shareImage{
        objectsToShare.append(shareImageObj)
    }

    if shareText != nil || shareImage != nil{
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

        present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else{
        print("There is nothing to share")
    }
}
```

Нашел ответ, может кому пригодится:

```
func actionShare(){

    //var messageStr:String  = "Check out my awesome iPicSafe photo!"
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: newsAboutOne[indexImage].image))
    var img: UIImage = image.image!
    //var shareItems:Array = [img, messageStr]
    var shareItems:Array = [img]
    let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.print, UIActivityType.postToWeibo, UIActivityType.copyToPasteboard, UIActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivityType.postToVimeo]
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Нашел решение, ответ выше, может кому пригодится.